# Loop Failure in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a loop whose purpose is to iterate through a Google Sheet, which shall be identified as `sheet`, and treated as a two-dimensional array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < sheet.length; i++) {
  var currentDataset = sheet.getRange(i+1, 1);
  var currentData = currentDataset.getCell(1, 1).getValue();

  Logger.log(String(currentData));

  switch (String(currentData)) {
    case string:
      Logger.log("match");
      for (var ii = 0; ii < 16; ii++) {
        currentDataset.getCell(1, ii+1).setValue(data[ii]);
      }
      break;

    default:
      Logger.log("no match");
      break;
  }
}
```

If the first cell, `currentData`, in the current row, `currentDataset`, according to `i` matches in a `switch` statement with the String value `string`, another loop would iterate to replace the appropriate values in the respective row with successiindeces of `data`, an array. If the current cell value does not match, the `switch` would default and break, allowing the loop to iterate again.

When the function is called, the loop begins to iterate through the sheet, defaulting on all the mismatches. However, when the loop reaches the match, it skips it. Here are what the logs look like:

```
[17-12-08 08:20:13:909 PST] Mismatch Value
[17-12-08 08:20:13:910 PST] default
*** THIS IS WHERE THE MATCH VALUE SHOULD APPEAR ***
[17-12-08 08:20:14:389 PST] Mismatch Value
[17-12-08 08:20:14:390 PST] default
```

I rewrote the code above to make variables more readable as it was originally in GAS, please comment if you require more detailed code, or find it here (lines 51 - 62): https://github.com/organism/Scorecard-Builder/blob/master/src/scorecardBuilder.gs

Comment: well 1st of all  `var currentDataset = sheet.getRange(i+1, 1);` is a range with only one cell in it so you won't be able to iterate through it. Also, I'm pretty sure the reason why you code doesn't do anything is because it always goes in the default option of you switch, so it breaks everytime and doesn't do anything.

Comment: What does the 1st row of your spreadsheet look like?

Comment: @LioraHaydont , `currentData` is supposed to be only the first column in the given row. Second of all, the break only scopes out of the switch statement, not the loop, or at least it should. Third of all, the first row is exactly the same as all the other rows, with a string in the first cell.

Comment: is your variable `string` set somewhere? I know the break only breaks out of the switch, I just think you end up in default for every loop so that's why the script doesn't do anything but shows no error

Comment: @LioraHaydont yes `string` is actually from an object `values` but nevertheless it is a String that exists. And I have tested it with matched embedded in the sheet and it still does not stop at the matches.

Comment: Try placing a Logger.log(String(currentData)) before the switch, and Logger.log("matched!")/Logger.log("default") for each options, this way you'll be sure oh where the code is passing.

Comment: So you think two strings are equal, but the script disagrees. How to settle that? Logging both strings is one way.  (As Liora suggested)

Comment: @LioraHaydont , the loop skips the match value. It seems to find it correctly, but rather than stopping there and allowing the embedded loop to run, it simply breaks and moves on to the next row.

Comment: @organism.exe I'm not sure to understand what you mean. the logger prints match but doesn't enter the enbedded loop? Try logging data inside the loop.

Comment: @liorahaydont the logs show the default break for every mismatch dataset, but when it reaches the match, nothing is logged and nothing happens, it just skips it and moves on

Comment: @organism.exe can you show us the logs you get when running the function?

Comment: @LioraHaydont just added a model of the logs.

Comment: @organism.exe can you replace `Logger.log(String(currentData));` by `Logger.log(String(currentData) + ' = ' + string + ' ? ' + (String(currentData) == string).toString());`? this way we can see why the values don't match when they should

Comment: @LioraHaydont I've added that and the loop stops running at the match. It matches successfully and enters the proper case scope, however it seems to get stuck within the embedded loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160824/discussion-between-organism-exe-and-liora-haydont).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were trying to do:

```
function myfunction(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();//or whatever
  var rg=ss.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();//gets all the data on the sheet
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    switch(typeof(vA[i][0])){
      case 'string':
        Logger.log('Match=%s',vA[i][0]);
        for(var j=0;j<16;j++){
          sh.getRange(i+1,j+1).setValue(vA[i][0])
        }
        break;
      default:
        Logger.log('No Match=%s',vA[i][0]);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Spreadsheet before running:

[image]

Spreadsheet After Running:

[image]

My Logger Output:

[image]

If that's not what you were shooting for then I'm sorry to interject myself here.

Comment: Not quite. Each row contains a string value in the first column, then integer values in every following column in that row. The script is supposed to stop at a matched first cell, then fill in the rest of the columns with their respective integer values according to an external object.